# Azure SQL database open in Visual Studio 2017 but foreign key not showing

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database

I have created an Azure SQL database with EF code-first. And one of the tables contains a foreign key. Earlier it worked fine and showing all key relationship (PK & FK).

[image]

But now I am not able to see the FK relationship in the table. It shows the key in the key folder. It happens with Visual Studio.

Problem is the navigation properties affected in our existing project.

[image]

Comment: Did you reconnect the Azure SQL database and refresh with SQL Server Express in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I am trying to connect Azure SQL database in visual studio.
And In SQL server express it looking good.
The problem occurs with visual studio and it affects the Entity FK navigation property.